# Regex for comparing special Characters in (C)Strings

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, mfc

I have an MFC project where I need to read and compare various configuration strings from  (xml-)files.

The problem is that they could contain one or multiple special characters like STX, ETX, LF, CR ... and so on.

An idea is using regex. I could simply write the full regex pattern in the files and compare them with a match function.

As I looked this up via google and msdn, there were two different(?) regex frameworks for MFC but I don't see any difference between them nor do I see if they can solve my problem, meaning handle special characters.

Do any of you have an experience with those frameworks? Can you recommend one or can you think of another solution for this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Might it not be enough with e.g. [`strspn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strspn) or [`strcspn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcspn) to find these characters?

Comment: It might work, however there is still the problem, that I read from the XML file "\n" (2 characters) and I need a line feed (1 character). I would have to check and replace all special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend std::regex or boost::regex over non standard alternatives. Also, they are able to support special characters.